# CSS3 Folding Animation with vertex

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I need to fold a squared `div` with vertex. I found some examples in Internet to fold edges in a squared `div`. Someone know how can I make this animation? This is an example in flash but I want the same in CSS3 and HTML5.

Thanks for your help.

[this is the example: Adidas](http://www.adidas.com/com/apps/neointeractivess13/)

Comment: http://www.awwwards.com/stunning-resources-for-paper-folding-animation-effect.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this  simple HTML

```
<div id="base">
<div id="clip">
<div id="image">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

you set this CSS:

```
div {
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#base {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
#clip {
    width: 290px;
    height: 290px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
}
#image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, red, blue);
}

#base:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1,1,0,-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
}
```

Starting from a **base** square div, you rotate an inner div 45deg. this div will **clip** the other thru the diagonal.
Inside this one, you set another div with the **image**, counter rotated 45 deg to keep the image horizontal.
And you set in the hover the base the div to rotate in 3d around the diagonal

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/yLzV9/)